# Cannot write value to hkey_classes_root\CLSID when installing in "Just for me" mode

Tags: windows, registry

I create "setup project" on Visual studio 2008. I need to write value into HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID. I know about registry redirector and file system redirector. I have found solution to fix it. And it works when I install app for "every one", intaller create registry key successfully. But when I choose "Intall just for me" intaller throw exception: "Exception enumerated open registry key". Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write either to `HKCU` (just for me) or `HKLM` (everyone); their merged view is `HKCR`.